# How to make a script to make multiple grep's over a file?

Tags: bash

I want to make a script that can do the following automatically:

```
 grep 'string1' file.txt | grep 'string2' | grep 'string3' ... | grep 'stringN'
```

The idea is that the script can be run like this:

```
myScript.sh file.txt string1 string2 string3 ... stringN
```

and the script has to return all the lines of `file.txt` that contain all the strings.

For instance, if `file.txt` looks like this:

```
hello world 
hello world run 
hello planet world
```

And I can make a grep like this:

```
grep hello file.txt | grep world
```

and I get:

```
hello world 
hello world run 
hello planet world
```

I want to make a script that makes this automatically, with an undefined number of strings as parameters.

I found that it is hard to achieve this, since the number of strings can be variable. First, I tried to create an array called `args` like this in `myScript.sh`:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 args=("$@")
```

with the purpose of storing the arguments. I know that the `${args[0]}` is going to be my `file.txt` and the rest are the strings that I need to use in the distinct greps, but I don't know how to proceed and if this is the best approach to solve the problem. I would appreciate any suggestion about how to program this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is capable of doing this perfectly with a single process, and avoids these `eval` shenanigans.  The resulting script is actually quite simple.

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
shift
printf '\\?%s?!d\n' "$@" |
sed -f - "$file"
```

We generate a line of `sed` script for each expression; if the expression is not (`!`) found, we delete (`d`) this input line, and start over with the next one.

This assumes your `sed` accepts `-` as the argument to `-f` to read the script from standard input.  This is not completely portable; you would perhaps need to store the generated script in a temporary file instead if this is a problem.

This uses `?` as the internal regex separator.  If you need a literal `?` in one of the patterns, you will need to backslash-escape it.  In the general case, creating a script which finds an alternative separator which is in none of the search expressions would perhaps be possible, but at that point, I'd move to a proper scripting language (Python would be my preference) instead.

Comment: I don't know how to run your script, since I paste your code into a file called myScritpt.sh and I run myScript.sh file.txt string1 ... stringN , but it doesn't work, and i don't know why you wrote #!/bin/sh instead  #!/bin/bash, I believe that this can be done in bash script and it's unnecessary to use python in this simple case .

Comment: Bash is a superset of `sh` aka Bourne shell. There are no Bash-specific constructs in this script, but you are of course free to change the shebang to point to Bash if that makes you more comfortable somehow. Either way, you'd run the script simply with `./myScript.sh` after you `chmod +x` it (though I'd recommend against an explicit `.sh` extension for interactive commands; and this particular extension suggests a Bourne, not Bash, script).

Comment: This script is simple but not entirely robust. For your own personal use, and/or with its shortcomings and limitations properly documented, it's fine the way it is. For a tool for public distribution, I'd move to Python or Perl, simply because `sed` with user-supplied script fragments is challenging to make completely robust.

Comment: The script was missing a backslash, though; fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: yes it already works thanks for the support, i will take notice of your observations, this i also a great way to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the pattern of operation and save it in a variable:

```
pattern="$(printf 'grep %s file.txt' "$1"; printf ' | grep %s' "${@:2}" ; printf '\n')"
```

and then

```
eval "$pattern"
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                                          
foo bar
bar spam
egg

% grep_gen () { pattern="$(printf 'grep %s file.txt' "$1"; printf ' | grep %s' "${@:2}" ; printf '\n')"; eval "$pattern" ;}

% grep_gen foo bar                           
foo bar
```

Comment: thanks this approach  is very useful but i have to write the name of my file inside the pattern variable, and the idea is to run bash myScript.sh file.txt string1 ... stringN, i need to receive the name of the file also as a parameter of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the command in a loop and then use `eval` to evaluate it.
This is using `cat` so you can group all the `grep`.

```
#! /bin/bash

file="$1"
shift
args=( "$@" )


cmd="cat '$file'"
for a in "${args[@]}"
do
    cmd+=' | '
    cmd+="grep '$a'"
done

eval $cmd
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I wanted, I really appreciated  your help.

Comment: As always, `eval` is going to be a security problem.  If one of the arguments contains a single quote, for example, this will fail with an inscrutable error message. There are probably ways to break it in even more interesting ways, including ways which exploit any `sudo` privileges the invoking user may have, for example.

Comment: following the code of Diego i made my optimization.

Answer (score 1):

An eval-free alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp1="$(mktemp)"
temp2="$(mktemp)"

grep "$2" "$1" > temp1
for arg in "${@:3}"; do
    grep "$arg" temp1 > temp2
    mv temp2 temp1
done

cat temp1
rm temp1
```

`mktemp` generates a temporary file with a unique name and returns its name; it should be widely available.

The loop then executes `grep` for each argument and renames the second temp file for the next loop.

Comment: I suppose you could generate a single pipeline in a temporary script file instead, and get away with a both simpler and faster script.

Comment: @tripleee I thought about doing something like that, but how would you run the script then?

Comment: `sh /tmp/script <file`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the optimization of Diego Torres Milano's code and the answer to my original question:

```
#! /bin/bash
file=$1
shift
cmd="cat '$file'"
for 'a' in "$@"
do
   cmd+=" | grep '$a'"
done
eval $cmd
```

Comment: Good optimization. Don't forget the quotes around `"$file"` in case the file name contains whitespaces. Same for `"$@"` and`'$a'`.

Comment: ok thanks for the support, I understand now. the usage of the quotes, this was very useful.