# How to assign multiple bash variables from user input

Tags: bash

Using `read -p "ENTER 1 - 5 WORDS" v1 v2 v3 v4 v5` allows me to assign value to each of the variables `v` by typing them on the command line. Is this the most practical approach? Suppose I wanted to assign a larger number of variables. Would I list each of them in this same way? I have tried `read -p "ENTER 1-20 WORDS" {v1..v20}` which didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is not part of the sequence. Try this :

```
read -p "ENTER 1-20 WORDS" v{1..20}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read into an array with `read -a`:

```
$ read -a arr -p "Enter words: "
Enter words: v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
$ read -a arr -p "Enter words: "
Enter words: v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
```

This uses shell word splitting and assigns the input to the array `arr`, elements of which can then be accessed using `${arr[0]}`, `${arr[1]}` etc.

The main advantage is that the array holds exactly as many elements as you entered and you don't have to know in advance how many there will be.

Comment: Could you expand on this a little? I'm having trouble understanding. For instance, supposing I wanted to use `grep` to search for multiple strings entered without having any predetermined notion of what those strings will be or the number of strings that will be entered. If needed I can update the original question.

Comment: @user556068 It depends a bit on what you'd like to grep: all terms, or any of them. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275421/how-to-make-a-script-to-make-multiple-greps-over-a-file) asks about creating a grep command from multiple search terms. Or what exactly is it you don't quite understand?

Comment: "The main advantage is that the array holds exactly as many elements as you entered and you don't have to know in advance how many there will be." So if I wanted to grep any and/or all of an undetermined number of user defined terms using the array variable, how would I go about doing that? For instance, On run 1: I want to grep 3 random terms. On run 2: I want to grep a different set of 7 random terms. On run 3: I want to grep 4 random terms.

Comment: Its not so much the grep command i'm interested in. Understanding the array variables and how to apply them in a real world situation is the main thing. Grep is just an example command.

Comment: @user556068 [This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) is a pretty good overview.